# How to add new credit card type in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, credit-card

I need to add some news credit cards type to Magento 2 like:

```
"DC" => "Diners Club"
"EL" => "ELO"
```

I know that Magento 2 has the default credit card above:

```
"AE" => "American Express"
"VI" => "Visa"
"MC" => "MasterCard"
"DI" => "Discover"
"JCB" => "JCB"
"SM" => "Switch/Maestro"
"DN" => "Diners"
"SO" => "Solo"
"MI" => "Maestro International"
"MD" => "Maestro Domestic"
"OT" => "Other"
```

But how to add Diners Club and Elo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but seems like it should be possible to do it like this:

Create a basic custom module and in `/etc/payment.xml` add new CC types:

```
<payment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Payment:etc/payment.xsd">
    <credit_cards>
        <type id="DC" order="110">
            <label>Diners Club</label>
        </type>
        <type id="EL" order="120">
            <label>ELO</label>
        </type>
    </credit_cards>
</payment>
```

This should declare new types for the entire Magento app.

I think you also need this in `/etc/module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Payment"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```